# How to add extra memory space to "usr" partition in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: partitioning, gnome

Ubuntu showing error message that your "usr" is having small amount of memory. And this is my  memory image from gparted:

[image: memory image]

Please explain me how I can increase the size of the "usr" folder.

Comment: I would use the unallocated space after /dev/sda17 to create /dev/sda18 and put e.g. `/usr/lib` there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Can please explain me how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your important data first. Then follow these instructions very carefully:

1. Boot the system from a Live disk or USB.
2. Use Gparted to create an extra EXT4-formatted partition from the unallocated 11Gb space after `/dev/sda17`. Let's say it is called `/dev/sda18`.
3. Create three temporary mount points, say `/mnt/root`, `/mnt/usr/` and `/mnt/usrlib`.
4. Mount the existing root partition, `/dev/sda9`, on `/mnt/root` (this is necessary to modify `/etc/fstab` later on.)
5. Mount the existing partition containing `/usr`, that is `/dev/sda13`, on `/mnt/usr/`.
6. Mount the new empty partition `/dev/sda18` on `/mnt/usrlib`.
7. Copy the whole of `/mnt/usr/lib` over to `/mnt/usrlib`. Make absolutely sure you have an exact copy (preferably, use `rsync` repeatedly until nothing is transferred).
8. Enter an extra line in `/mnt/root/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/sda18` on mount point `/usr/lib`.
9. Reboot.

If everything works, and you can verify that `/usr/lib` is mounted on `/dev/sda18`, you have two copies of `/usr/lib`. To remove the one that you no longer need, in order to free up space, do the following:

1. Reboot from a live disk.
2. Mount `/dev/sda13` on a temporary mount point, say `/mnt/usr`.
3. Delete the contents of `/mnt/usr/lib`, but keep the empty directory, which will serve as the mount point.
4. Reboot.

*Other Askubuntu users are encouraged to review this procedure and point out errors and omissions.*

Comment: also, before we delete the contents of `/mnt/usr/lib`, shouldn't be the temporary mount-point just `/mnt`? Another point: when copying to the new partition we have to preserve permissions, ownership and attributes (you mentioned `exact copy`). An option would be to `move` instead of `copy`, we don't need to delete anything.afterwards.

Comment: @mook765 re first question: I don't recommend making  `/mnt` a mount point itself. Mount points should go inside `/mnt`. The disk `/dev/sda13` will have a top level folder `/lib` so it would seem natural to me to mount this in  `/mnt/usr`.

Comment: @mook765 `rsync` from one EXT4 partition to another will preserve ownership, permissions, etc., if used with the appropriate flags. Personally I don't like large move operations. They can be a nightmare to resume if they are for some reason aborted halfway. But that is a matter of preference, I use `rsync` a lot.